# Script to test for memory usage

Tags: bash, cron, memory

I'm trying to put up a temporary band-aid while I work out a solution for a app's memory leak. What I wrote was a small `bash` script that I put in the root on the server. This is what the script is suppose to do:

1. Get the location it's run in
2. Check to to see if the script is the crontab
3. If not in the crontab add to the crontab to run every 5mins
4. Test the memory and check to see if the % is above percent_allowed
5. If above test then restart nginx & php-fmp services

`memory_protect.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
cronfile=memory_protect.sh    #NOTE THIS SHOULD DETECT IT'S SELF
path=pwd                      #this is the path to the file 
percent_allowed=80            #this should be max memory before action

has_cron(){
    #is the file in the cron?
    return [[ crontab -l | egrep -v '^$|^#' | grep -q $cronfile ]] && return 1 || return 0
}
test_memory(){
    memusage=`top -n 1 -b | grep "Mem"`
    MAXMEM=`echo $memusage | cut -d" " -f2 | awk '{print substr($0,1,length($0)-1)}'`
    USEDMEM=`echo $memusage | cut -d" " -f4 | awk '{print substr($0,1,length($0)-1)}'`

    USEDMEM1=`expr $USEDMEM \* 100`
    PERCENTAGE=`expr $USEDMEM1 / $MAXMEM`
    #if it's above 80% alert
    return [[ $PERCENTAG>$percent_allowed ]] && return 1 || return 0
}

if [[ has_cron -eq 0 ]]
then
    #was not here so add
    #run this script every 5 mins
    */5 * * * $path/$cronfile
fi

if [[ test_memory ]]
then
    #clear some memory
    /etc/init.d/nginx restart
    /etc/init.d/php-fpm restart
fi
```

The memory test seems to work when I run that by it's self, but this in whole doesn't seem to be working.

---

**Update**
I needed to run `dos2unix` on the file, but I also realized I have a return on the conditions of each function in the end.. so that was not going to work.  Right now it seems to say that `[[` on the `if` statement is not found.

---

**Update 2**
Seems close, it's running the restarting of the services, but it's not putting the cron job in.. so I don't see it running

```
#!/bin/bash
cronfile=memory_protect.sh    #NOTE THIS SHOULD DETECT IT'S SELF
path=pwd                      #this is the path to the file 
percent_allowed=80            #this should be max memory before action

has_cron(){
    #is the file in the cron?
    #return 0 #returning this just to test should
    #be the next line but it's not working
    return 0
    [[ crontab -l | egrep -v '^$|^#' | grep -q $cronfile ]] && return 1 || return 0
}
test_memory(){
    memusage=`top -n 1 -b | grep "Mem"`
    MAXMEM=`echo $memusage | cut -d" " -f2 | awk '{print substr($0,1,length($0)-1)}'`
    USEDMEM=`echo $memusage | cut -d" " -f4 | awk '{print substr($0,1,length($0)-1)}'`

    USEDMEM1=`expr $USEDMEM \* 100`
    PERCENTAGE=`expr $USEDMEM1 / $MAXMEM`
    #if it's above 80% alert
    [[ $PERCENTAG -gt $percent_allowed ]] && return 1 || return 0
}

if [[ has_cron -eq 0 ]]
then
    #was not here so add
    #run this script every 5 mins
    #crontab -e */5 * * * $path/$cronfile
    cat <(crontab -l) <(echo "*/5 * * * $path/$cronfile") | crontab -
else
    echo "cron present"
fi

if [ test_memory ]
then
    #clear some memory
    sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart
    sudo /etc/init.d/php-fpm restart
fi
```

It's close now I think to being corrected.

Comment: @sim well the `has_cron` seems to be the current place of issue.  But when I ran it after once with `has_cron` returning a `0` it didn't set the task either.

Comment: @sim to set the cron job if it doesn't exist

Comment: You need to do a `crontab -e` to add to a user's crontab entry. Not sure how to do that from a script though, let me look it up. HERE: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/878600/how-to-create-cronjob-using-bash

Comment: I would never use kind of script, there are application to keep your application/server running and monitor , Example `monit`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a crontab entry via a Bash script you'll need to change this line:

```
*/5 * * * * $path/$cronfile
```

To something like this:

```
# Write out current crontab
crontab -l > mycron

# Echo new cron into cron file
echo "*/5 * * * * $path/$cronfile" >> mycron

# Install new cron file
crontab mycron
rm mycron
```

You could also get fancy and do it all with this one liner:

```
cat <(crontab -l) <(echo "*/5 * * * $path/$cronfile") | crontab -
```

#### Your script

Here's a modified version of your script that works for me.

```
#!/bin/sh

cronfile=memory_protect.sh    #NOTE THIS SHOULD DETECT IT'S SELF
path=$(pwd)                   #this is the path to the file 
percent_allowed=80            #this should be max memory before action

has_cron(){
    #is the file in the cron?
    #return 0 #returning this just to test should
    #be the next line but it's not working
    if crontab -l | egrep -v '^$|^#' | grep -q $cronfile; then
      return 1
    else
      return 0
    fi
}
test_memory(){
    memusage=$(top -n 1 -b | grep "Mem")
    MAXMEM=$(echo $memusage | cut -d" " -f2 | awk '{print substr($0,1,length($0)-1)}')
    USEDMEM=$(echo $memusage | cut -d" " -f4 | awk '{print substr($0,1,length($0)-1)}')

    USEDMEM1=$(expr $USEDMEM \* 100)
    PERCENTAGE=$(expr $USEDMEM1 / $MAXMEM)
    #if it's above 80% alert
    [[ $PERCENTAG>$percent_allowed ]] && return 1 || return 0
}

if has_cron;
then
    #was not here so add
    #run this script every 5 mins
    #crontab -e */5 * * * $path/$cronfile
    #cat <(crontab -l) <(echo "*/5 * * * $path/$cronfile") | crontab -
    crontab -l > mycron

    # Echo new cron into cron file
    echo "*/5 * * * * $path/$cronfile" >> mycron

    # Install new cron file
    crontab mycron
    rm mycron
else
    echo "cron present"
fi

if test_memory;
then
    #clear some memory
    echo "/etc/init.d/nginx restart"
    echo "/etc/init.d/php-fpm restart"
fi
```

#### Example

```
$ ./memory_protect.sh 
/etc/init.d/nginx restart
/etc/init.d/php-fpm restart

$ crontab -l
*/5 * * * * /home/saml/tst/91789/memory_protect.sh
```

The script needs to have these two lines modified so that it will actually restart the `nginx` and `php-fpm` services.

Change these lines:
        echo "/etc/init.d/nginx restart"
        echo "/etc/init.d/php-fpm restart"

To these:

```
    /etc/init.d/nginx restart
    /etc/init.d/php-fpm restart
```

I did this just so I could see that the script was running correctly. NOTE: that these restart lines should be prefixed with `sudo` if this script is running as anyone other than root!

sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart
        sudo /etc/init.d/php-fpm restart

This use will likely need to have `NOPASSWD` privileges at least on these 2 scripts otherwise it will be waiting for the user that owns the cron to supply a password.

#### Crontab entry doesn't exist?

You'll encounter this problem when your crontab hasn't been created yet in the directory, `/var/sppol/cron`. You'll encounter it when you run `crontab -l` like this:

```
$ crontab -l
no crontab for saml
```

Double check:

```
$ sudo ls -l /var/spool/cron/
total 0
-rw------- 1 root root 0 Sep 16 23:47 root
```

So just simply make like you're going to edit it, and save the empty file to create it:

```
$ crontab -e

# now you're in the vim editor, add a empty line
# type "i", hit return, hit Escape,
# and do a Shift + Z + Z to save!
```

Now you should see this:

```
$ crontab -l
$
```

And this:

```
$ sudo ls -l /var/spool/cron/
total 0
-rw------- 1 root root 0 Sep 16 23:47 root
-rw------- 1 saml root 0 Sep 21 16:20 saml
```

#### Restarting the services

Another issue you'll run into is if this crontab entry is running as user, user1, then user1 will require `sudo` rights to restart them.

Comment: so I just get a `: not foundect.sh: 4: ` return.   I changed the line `return [[ $PERCENTAG>"80" ]] && return 1 || return 0` to add quotes on the 80 as it was complaining about that

Comment: @jeremyBass_DC - can you update your Q with the new problem? I'm not following what you're saying.

Comment: so when I check for the cron job with `crontab -l` I just get `no crontab for vagrant`.  Vagrant is the user.  But not seeing anything .. and when I check for root it has none either

Comment: @jeremyBass_DC - look at my version of your script, I fixed that too. Need to tell Bash to exec `$(pwd)` not the string "pwd".

Comment: @jeremyBass_DC - OK it only took like 2 hours, I understand what you're doing now, sorry it's a Saturday, see my updates. The `[[ ... ]]` blocks weren't doing what you thought. You can use the `if ..cmd..` bare without them as long as you do the returns as you are.

Comment: @jeremyBass_DC - to restart those services from this cron you'll have to setup sudo rights, you can make them passwordless so that the cron can restart these as you're trying to.

Comment: @jeremyBass_DC - yes `sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart`.

Comment: @jeremyBass_DC - if you login as root are there emails of the errors? They typically get sent via email to root.

Comment: @jeremyBass_DC - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vagrant-up/xMWKkKW24xs. I think I usually do it like this: `vagrant ssh`, from my host, and then `sudo su -` to become root.

Comment: Ubuntu the logs are here: `grep CRON /var/log/syslog`

Comment: @jeremyBass_DC - yeah so that atleast confirms that your script is running, what is the odd behavior then?

Comment: well I was expecting to see the echos, but reading up on the MTA message, it's trying to mail the echo? ..

Comment: @jeremyBass_DC - do me a huge favor and delete comments above that aren't relevant? thanks.

Comment: @jeremyBass_DC - yeah cron emails any output to stdout.

Comment: yeah it was getting a little long, and I'll delete this one ..

Answer (score 2):

I would use [monit](http://mmonit.com/wiki/Monit/Suggestions) for this

Here is monit script example, for your requirement

```
check process nginx with pidfile /var/run/nginx.pid
  start program = "/etc/init.d/nginx start"
  stop program  = "/etc/init.d/nginx stop"
  if memory usage > 95% then restart
  group www-data 
  if 5 restarts within 5 cycles then timeout
```

Try to restart 5 times; if monit cannot restart webserver 5 times; just time out to avoid race condition.

[Reference Link](http://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html)